# QtWebengine 5.15.10 with proprietary codecs, build problems on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, chromium, h.264, qtwebengine

I wrote an application with QtWebEngine, but I need support for the h264 codec and QtWebEngine doesn't include it by default because of patent problems, or so I heard.
That's why I decided to build QtWebEngine from source and enable proprietary codecs.
I can't use the latest Qt6-based QtWebEngine, so I chose the most recent Qt5 version, which is 5.15.10.

```
# Installing dependencies:
sudo apt install gperf perl flex bison python2 libnss3-dev qtdeclarative5-private-dev
sudo apt install libdrm-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcomposite1 libnx-x11-dev libxkbfile-dev libxtst-dev libxdamage-dev  libxdamage1 libxrandr-dev libxrandr2 libxkbfile-dev libxkbfile1 libx11-xcb-dev


# Getting source code
git clone -b 5.15.10 https://github.com/qt/qtwebengine.git
cd qtwebengine
git submodule update --init --recursive

# Checking versions of Python and g++
python --version
> Python 2.7.18
g++ --version
> g++ (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0

# Creating build directory and building
mkdir build
cd build
qmake .. -- -proprietary-codecs
make -j4 -l4
```

It manages to build most of the source, but then I get this message:

```
[16150/25745] /usr/bin/g++ -MMD -MF obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/congestion_controller/rtp/control_handler/control_handler.o.d -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_OZONE=1 -DOFFICIAL_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_QT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -DNO_UNWIND_TABLES -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -DWEBRTC_ENABLE_PROTOBUF=1 -DRTC_ENABLE_VP9 -DHAVE_SCTP -DENABLE_EXTERNAL_AUTH -DWEBRTC_USE_H264 -DHAVE_WEBRTC_VIDEO -DLOGGING_INSIDE_WEBRTC -DWEBRTC_LIBRARY_IMPL -DWEBRTC_NON_STATIC_TRACE_EVENT_HANDLERS=0 -DWEBRTC_CHROMIUM_BUILD -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DABSL_ALLOCATOR_NOTHROW=1 -DNO_MAIN_THREAD_WRAPPING -Igen -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc_overrides -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc -Igen/third_party/webrtc -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/abseil-cpp -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/perfetto/include -Igen/third_party/perfetto/build_config -Igen/third_party/perfetto -Igen -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/libyuv/include -Igen -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fPIC -pipe -pthread -m64 -Wall -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-comments -Wno-packed-not-aligned -Wno-dangling-else -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -std=gnu++14 -Wno-narrowing -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-attributes -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-subobject-linkage -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-return-type -Wno-deprecated-copy -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -c ../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc/modules/congestion_controller/rtp/control_handler.cc -o obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/congestion_controller/rtp/control_handler/control_handler.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make[3]: *** [Makefile.gn_run:436: run_ninja] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/max/Documents/qtwebengine/build/src/core'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:82: sub-gn_run-pro-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/max/Documents/qtwebengine/build/src/core'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:80: sub-core-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/max/Documents/qtwebengine/build/src'
make: *** [Makefile:49: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

Then I try to run this command manually:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -MMD -MF obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/congestion_controller/rtp/control_handler/control_handler.o.d -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_OZONE=1 -DOFFICIAL_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_QT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -DNO_UNWIND_TABLES -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -DWEBRTC_ENABLE_PROTOBUF=1 -DRTC_ENABLE_VP9 -DHAVE_SCTP -DENABLE_EXTERNAL_AUTH -DWEBRTC_USE_H264 -DHAVE_WEBRTC_VIDEO -DLOGGING_INSIDE_WEBRTC -DWEBRTC_LIBRARY_IMPL -DWEBRTC_NON_STATIC_TRACE_EVENT_HANDLERS=0 -DWEBRTC_CHROMIUM_BUILD -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DABSL_ALLOCATOR_NOTHROW=1 -DNO_MAIN_THREAD_WRAPPING -Igen -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc_overrides -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc -Igen/third_party/webrtc -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/abseil-cpp -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/perfetto/include -Igen/third_party/perfetto/build_config -Igen/third_party/perfetto -Igen -I../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/libyuv/include -Igen -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fPIC -pipe -pthread -m64 -Wall -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-comments -Wno-packed-not-aligned -Wno-dangling-else -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -std=gnu++14 -Wno-narrowing -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-attributes -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-subobject-linkage -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-return-type -Wno-deprecated-copy -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -c ../../../../src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc/modules/congestion_controller/rtp/control_handler.cc -o obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/congestion_controller/rtp/control_handler/control_handler.o
```

To run it manually, I change directory to

```
cd src/core/release
```

and run this command. It works and the file compiles successfully, so I'm not sure if this particular file causes any problems. But the build fails anyway.

I have 24 GB of RAM and memory consumption during the build never goes above 8 GB, when I look at

```
htop
```

during the build.

Also I don't see any out of memory(OOM) errors when I run

```
sudo dmesg
```

I did a fair amount of Googling and forum reading, but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix.
It turns out QtWebEngine uses system Ninja by default, but also has its own Ninja.
I read that using system Ninja can cause problems, so I switched to QtWebEngine Ninja by adding

```
-no-feature-webengine-system-ninja
```

to qmake, like so:

```
qmake .. -- -proprietary-codecs -no-feature-webengine-system-ninja
```

Comment: Hi, I see you had worked out QtWebEngine  compilation on ubuntu, Would you plz take a look at this problem. https://forum.qt.io/topic/138824/succeeded-in-compiling-qtwebengine-of-qt6-3-1-on-ubuntu22-04-but-failed-in-importing-it-into-my-own-project